# making a single equation larger inside \begin{align} … \end{align}

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, fontsize

Hello you wonderful TeX friends!

I have an issue making a single equation that bigger.

I'm restricted to use the `align` environment for my equations. I've used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3705/22939)  to make inline math bigger, and I looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238254/22939), but it's as the `align` environment is a bit tricky here. I would however like to stick to that. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
2+2 = 4 \\
2=3 = 5 % I only want to make this single line bigger
\end{align}

% I'm aware I can something like this,

\begin{align}
2+2 = 4 
\end{align}
\vspace{-15mm}
{\LARGE 
\begin{align}
2+3 = 5 
\end{align}
}

% but that enlarges the equation number, 
% and I don't want that, along withing
%  adding \end{align} … \begin{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i'm not in a position to test anything, but `amsart` goes to some effort to keep the equation number the same size, regardless of the size applied to the content of the display.  you may be able to steal the method from there.

Comment: Your LaTeX code is confusing. For instance, no use is made of alignment points inside the `align` environments, and the first `align` environment is missing a line-break directive between the rows. Is this deliberate?

Comment: @Mico, thanks for the heads up, I've updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

Although the example code uses `align` there are no alignment points specified, which means that you can use a simpler setup such as `gather`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
2+2 = 4 \\
 % I only want to make this single line bigger
\mbox{\LARGE$\displaystyle2=3 = 5$}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am however restricted to use `align`.

Comment: @EricFail (you could just use the above with align) but it makes no sense, (sorry:-) saying you have to use `align` even when there is no alignment is like saying you have to use `color` to make black text or `\textsubscript` to make a superscript. Of course any of these things are possible but why????